# mongodb and Ambari cluster integration

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to install and configure a Mongodb cluster on Ambari but the installation is failing. It is showing as MongoDB Server   Install Failed. But the Slave nodes are installed and running fine. Please help me out to fix this issue?

Comment: Try including the error details you are seeing in your question, otherwise people don't know what is wrong and can't offer guidance.